# Applying normal (non-implicit) curvature equation to implicit planar curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I have recently learned about curvature for plane curves. I understand the derivation for the non-parametric version of the formula and the parametric version of the formula; however, for the context of this question, I would like to focus on the non-parametric version of the formula.

From what I understand, for an arbitrary function $f(x)$, its curvature can be expressed as:
$$\kappa = \frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$

Now, let us consider a simple implicit function such as the unit circle given by $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Implicitly differentiating, we obtain:
$$\begin{align} \frac{dy}{dx} &= -\frac{x}{y} \\ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} &= \frac{-y+xy'}{y^2} = \frac{-y^2-x^2}{y^3} = -\frac{1}{y^3} \end{align}$$

Thus, we can calculate the curvature as:
$$\kappa= -1$$

Disregarding the sign for now, I'm just surprised that this formulation for curvature works at all for an implicit function, considering the fact that an implicit function does not pass the vertical line test. Is there some deeper reason why this is so, or is the example I have provided just a one-off example?

Furthermore, does the negative sign have any meaning in this context? I know that in normal situations, the negative sign comes up when the curve is described in the "negative" direction i.e. the area enclosed by the curve is on our right hand side as we trace out the curve. However, I don't think this concept really applies to implicit curves.

I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your calculation of $\kappa$. We have
$$
\left(1+(y’)^2\right)^{1/2}
= \left(1+\left(\frac xy \right)^2\right)^{1/2}
= \left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)^{1/2}
= \frac{1}{|y|}.
$$
Therefore we get
$$
\kappa = \frac{-1/y^3}{1/|y|^3} = - \mathrm{sign}(y). 
$$
In other words, $\kappa$ is $-1$ on the upper semicircle and $+1$ on the lower semicircle. Thus, the formula works as expected, i.e. the curvature is calculated in the direction of increasing $x$-values, and it’s discontinuous at $(\pm1, 0)$.

As for your general question, implicit differentiation is really nothing but another way of calculating the derivative, so everything will work as expected. The only problem points are places with vertical tangents. In these cases, another definition of (or rather formula for) curvature is needed.

Comment: I believe your denominator term is incorrect; I am pretty sure the denominator term is meant to be $(1+y’^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ Take a look at: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature

Comment: @DavidChoi Yes, we agree! $(1+(y')^2)^\frac32 = \left((1+(y')^2)^\frac12\right)^3 = \frac{1}{|y|^3}$.

Comment: @DavidChoi My first equations were just meant to show a certain part of the calculation, not the whole denominator. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: I found on the web a formulation of curvature for implicit curves using partial derivatives. I'm assuming this formulation works for all points of the implicit curve, even vertical tangents?

Comment: @DavidChoi Yes it does, but note that you won't get a signed curvature, only an absolute value. That's unavoidable since an implicit curve doesn't have a canonical orientation.

Comment: @DavidChoi You can still run into the rare case that both partial derivatives are $0$ at a point – then even that formula breaks down. For example $x^2=0$ corresponds to the vertical line through the origin, but it's a pathological case.

Comment: I see but I guess what I really want to know is why is there a separate formulation for curvature for implicit curves when the standard formulation works for most, well behaved points? What’s the fundamental difference between the two formulations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131218/discussion-between-milten-and-david-choi).